# Topological sort of partial order into sorted sets

Tags: order-theory

Given a partial order of elements, one can use topological sorting to produce a sorted list of elements. For example, if we have the partial order A->B and A->C, then the possible topological sort results are [A,B,C] and [A,C,B].

I am interested in producing a sorted list of **sets** [$S_1, \ldots, S_k$] that satisfy the partial order. (The sets $S_i$ partition the elements.) Here, the requirements are:

1. for $i = 1 \ldots k-1$, $\exists e_1 \in S_i,e_2 \in S_{i+1}$ s.t. $e_1 < e_2$
2. for each set $S_i$, $\nexists e_1, e_2 \in S_i$ such that $e_1 < e_2$ or $e_2 < e_1$

In our example, the only correct sorted list of sets is [{A},{B,C}]. Given a partial order, how many possible sorted lists of sets exist? Is there a name for this kind of sorting? Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear whether the sets S_i form a partition of your original set.  If they do, then (I think) you are looking for homomorphic images of your partial order, and that is bounded by the number of partitions of the set.  If you allow an element to belong to different S_i, that changes things, but may still be tied to homomorphic images of the original partial order for connected partial orders.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.04.14

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I meant S_i to form a partition. BTW, I have rewritten condition 1. 

Comment: This new version doesn't really sound like it's "sorted": look at the partial order A<B, C<D with no other comparable pairs; then [{A,D},{B,C}] satisfies the conditions even though D occurs in an earlier set than C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: This answer was for a previous version of the question.

There is usually no such list: consider the case where some element is incomparable to everything else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just realized I did not properly formulate the problem and have fixed condition 1. So if there is an element that is incomparable to everything else, then you can place it in any existing set in the sorted list. 

Comment: Or consider a pentagon-shaped partial order, with one vertex having out degree 2 and indegree 0, and a vertex two edges away having indegree 2 and outdegree 0, with remaining vertices ghavin in and out degree 1.  That will not admit a partition of the desired form.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.04.14

Comment: Hi Gerhard, I'm not completely understanding the example (you mean diamond shape, not pentagon, right?). So if we have a partial relation A->B, A->C, C->D, B->D, then I can create the sorted list [{A},{B,C},{D}]. Let me know if I got this wrong. 

Comment: I think Gerhard truly means pentagon.  A->B, B->C, C->D, A->E, and E->D.

Comment: But in the pentagon with the notation in my previous comment, [{A}, {B,E}, {C}, {D}] seems to satisfy the requirements.  

Comment: Mere existence of an appropriate partition seems to be OK in any finite poset.  Put an element $x$ into `$S_i$` iff $i$ is the largest length of any maximal chain below $x$.  Equivalently, let `$S_1$` consist of the minimal elements of your poset $P$, `$S_2$` the minimal elements of `$P-S_1$`, etc.  Of course, this doesn't come close to solving the original problem of counting the number of such partitions.

Comment: Hi Andreas, I was about to give the same response for the pentagon example. I also agree there exists an algorithm that returns one possible solution. As you said, I am interested in the counting problem. It is unclear if there are polynomial or exponentially many possible orderings in terms of the number of elements. For instance, if there is no partial order in the universe {A,B,C}, then there is just one solution [{A,B,C}] and not an exponential number of solutions. 

Comment: OK, now I see that the count can indeed be exponential to the # of elements. 

Comment: The pentagon example referred to an earlier version where e.g. a in S_1 and b in S_2 implied a < b.   Then A,B,C, and D had to be in separate sets, but E could not be placed in any of those because of the (now omitted) implication. Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.04.14

Answer (score 1):

We can take $S_1$ to be the set of minimal elements, then remove those and proceed inductively. Or go in the other direction, pealing off the maximal elements first. So in any case such lists do exist.